# How to copy text from one Text Box to other using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer

I want to **get text in a variable from Text Box** and **paste the value from variable to another Text Box**. Or please suggest me to **copy text from one Text Box to another Text Box** on the click of the Push Button.

Comment: I suggest you copy the text from one text box to another text box on the click of the push button.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to button clicked event:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.copy_text)
```

Implement `copy_text` method:

```
def copy_text(self):
    text = self.textBox1.text()
    self.textBox2.setText(text)
```